# What is the difference between Red Hat Enterprise Linux boot ISO and the same Binary DVD

Tags: rhel, iso, dvd

I am still confused after an hour searching what is the difference and when someone would need just boot ISO or binary DVD ISO 
Can someone explain in a simple way the difference between them.
The only visible difference is the size and the checksum, but this is obvious :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Understanding the various RHEL .iso files](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/104063)

> boot.iso
>
> Used to install the operating system from another source
>   (such as a http repository of the binary files). Can also be used to
>   enter Rescue Mode.
>
> Binary DVD
>
> The discs required to install and use Red Hat Enterprise
>   Linux. Can also be used to enter Rescue Mode.